# Character parsing for new variable

Tags: string, parsing, char

I got the character with the value:
('2'; 0x32 excluding the brackets).
I'd like the give another variable the value between the ' ', in this case the 2.

Let's say char j='2'; 0x32 ;
int i ;
I've tried:
i=j[1];

I want to take the second variable (2) within the character j, but it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: 0x32 is the ASCII/Unicode value in base 16 (50 decimal) of the character `'2'`. Maybe you saw it in the debugger. `int i = j;` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you got this value, because in the ASCII / Unicode table, `0x32` (or `50` in decimal) and character `2` are the same.

Perhaps you have errors in how you get this value. If not, then `int i = j;` will help.